# POSTing HTML from form to another page...formatting getting messed up

Tags: php, post

So I am trying to POST a string from a form to another page.

```
<form role="form" action="http://domain.com/nextpage.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" 
     style="display:none" 
     name="html-address" 
     value="<span class="street-address">10628 Park Rd</span><span class="locality">Charlotte</span><span class="region">NC</span> <span class="postal-code">28210</span><span class="country-name">USA</span></div>">
</form>
```

I want the string that I posted to fill into a div on the next page, like this:

```
<div id="hidden-address"> <?php echo $_POST["html-address"];?> </div>
```

Ideally, the resulting page should look like this:

```
<div id="hidden-address">
    <span class="street-address">10628 Park Rd</span>
    <span     class="locality">Charlotte</span>
    <span class="region">NC</span> 
    <span class="postal-code">28210</span>
    <span class="country-name">USA</span>
</div>
```

However, it appears as if the formatting is getting messed up.  It looks like this:

```
<div id="hidden-address"> 
    <span class="\&quot;street-address\&quot;">10628 Park Rd</span>, 
    <span class="\&quot;locality\&quot;">Charlotte</span>, 
    <span class="\&quot;region\&quot;">NC</span> 
    <span class="\&quot;postal-code\&quot;">28210</span>, 
    <span class="\&quot;country-name\&quot;">USA</span> 
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this formatting issue?

Comment: You could try like `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["html-address"], ENT_IGNORE);`

Comment: you can either change the inner double quotes `"` to single quotes `'`, or make sure before you output your string you `unescape` it to convert the `&quot;` back to `"`

Comment: You want to accept user input and display it on a page, including HTML elements? This is not a good idea.

Comment: Your HTML markup is full of errors. Use [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) to discover them.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unescape/decode the sent data. One of the methods is [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode).

However, I'd strongly suggest you don't send the whole HTML like that, but make separate fields for each property and then rebuild it on the landing page.